# How do I use vlookup in VBA to enter a value into that cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use vlookup in VBA in a command button to enter a value after determining what row the data should go into. Is there a better way to do this? I want the button to look up the name typed in and enter the new number to the appropriate row.

***This is the place that I am trying to enter the value into.***
[image]

Comment: Please show the code you have tried, it is easier for us to help you.

Comment: The better way to do is using vba code. Do you have any question about your actual code?

Comment: Is the button an ActiveX Control or a Form Control?

Comment: Reading [ask] and modifying your question accordingly will help you understand how to help us help you more efficiently.

Comment: @DavidG. VBA code is what I was hoping to get help on.

Comment: @SilentRevolution it is a Active X Control

Comment: Then you are in the wrong place @MrSparkyP. We don't develop code for your needs, we provide you FREE assistance for your own code.

Comment: @DavidG.  I have code for it but its close to useless because I have had to teach myself everything I know on VBA. I'll look for help somewhere else then. Sorry for the misunderstanding. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @MrSparkyP Don't do yourself a disservice. Many of us are self-taught and initial posts (and sometime later ones too) can be a bit of a learning curve but consider this.... sharing your code teaches you the valuable skill of code review/partner working, gives us better insight into where problems might lie including any assumptions you may not have stated, gets you used to editing code and learning how to format it.... to mention a few skills. Ultimately, it helps us to help you.

Comment: Over time you will feel much more comfortable doing so. SO has lots of volunteers willing to give their time in return for some code to work with.

Comment: @QHarr Thank you

Comment: Good on you for sticking with it i say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub MyReplace()
Dim rw As Long
With ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
        rw = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Range("B13"), .Range("B4:B7"), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rw > 0 Then
        .Range("C" & rw + .Range("B4:B7").Row - 1).Value = .Range("C13")
    Else
        MsgBox "Name not found in range"
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not very experienced in VBA so I am not sure what the error message i received means but when I tried this it says there is a Application-defined or object-defined error. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: On which line? @MrSparkyP

Comment: @MrSparkyP see edit.  had a typo.  The main difference between mine and JohnyL. Is I put it in error handling to deal with the chance that the user may not type the correct name.

Comment: Its something to do on the 3rd line. With ActiveSheet it gives that error but if I change ActiveSheet to the sheet name it returns the error message.

Comment: @MrSparkyP sorry had a typo see the edit, I forgot to hit the submit button.  It is there now.

Comment: Awesome that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without error handler:

```
Sub F()
    With [B3:C7]
        .Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match([B13], .Columns(1), 0), 2) = [C13]
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If the entry in B13 does not match any in the range it will error and stop. otherwise good.

Comment: @ScottCraner Perhaps, this is why there's a warning before code :)

Answer (score 0):

If the button is an `ActiveX` control, you can tap into the sheet module `CommandButton_Click`event and add the following sub to the sheet itself.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()  'Change CommandButton1 to the actual name of your button
    Dim i As Long
    Dim blnRecorded As Boolean

    With Me
        For i = 4 To .Cells(4, 2).End(xlDown).Row
            If .Cells(i, 4) = .Cells(4, 3) Then
                .Cells(i, 5) = .Cells(4, 4)
                blnRecorded = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i

        If Not blnRecorded Then
            MsgBox "The typed name does not match any employee in the table"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```